# How to convert line breaks to BR in summernote WYSIWYG text area

Tags: javascript, php, summernote

I use summernote as WYSIWYG editor for text area
I did move al DB where text was saved with line breaks and output with nl2br

The issue is that summernote does not show line breaks as new line
It is showing everything on one line because line breaks are ignored

Any way to display or convert line breaks to BR?